# HTML5 Video covering elements in Safari despite z-index settings

Tags: html, video, safari

I have a `#hero` div that contains a `video` and a `.headline` div. On all browsers except Safari, it renders with the video autoplaying with the `headline` div overlaid on top of the video. In Safari, the `.headline` div remains behind the `video` no matter what I do to the z-indexes of both elements. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Code below. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
  `<div id="hero" class="col s12 valign-wrapper">
  <video class="hide-on-small-only responsive-video col s12" autoplay muted loop>          
    <source src="<?php echo $video_url; ?>" type="video/mp4"> 
  </video>
  <div class="col l4 offset-l6 s12 valign headline">
    <div class="headline-inner">
    <h1><?php print render($content['field_hero_headline']); ?></h1>
    <p><?php print render($content['field_hero_body']); ?></p>
    <a download class="btn" href="<?php echo $download_url; ?>"><?php print render($content['field_hero_button_text']); ?></a>
    </div> <!--.headline-inner-->
  </div> <!--.headline-->
</div> <!--.hero-->`
```

CSS

`#hero {position: relative; width: 100%;}
.headline {background-color: #ffffff; position: absolute; border-left: 3px solid #0053b9;}`

Comment: Maybe your grid styles are colliding with your styles. Check your html without grid styles.

Comment: Yeah @Hokusai I think you're on to something. I tried removing some grid styles in the safari inspector and the div reappeared.